# Flutter NestedScrollView and SliverAppBar within AutoTabsRouter and nested Scaffolds as children is not working?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, nestedscrollview, sliverappbar

Here is my code. The Appbar stays static when I scroll down.
If you need more of the code, let me know.

I'm using auto_route flutter and the routes InvestHomeRouter() and BonusHomeRouter() lead to other scaffolds that have no own appbar and have singleChildScrollviews as bodys.

I want the parent scaffold to hide the appbar if the children scaffolds detect any scrolling down.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  `const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: AutoTabsRouter(
            routes: [
          InvestHomeRouter(),
          BonusHomeRouter()
        ],
            builder: (context, child, animation) {
             
              final tabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(context);
              
              return HomeScaffold(
                tabsRouter: tabsRouter,
                child: child,
                animation: animation,
              );
            }));
  }
}

class HomeScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScaffold(
      {required this.tabsRouter,
      required this.animation,
      required this.child,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final Animation<double> animation;
  final TabsRouter tabsRouter;
  @override
  State<HomeScaffold> createState() => _HomeScaffoldState();
}

class _HomeScaffoldState extends State<HomeScaffold> {
  int activeIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        floatHeaderSlivers: true,
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
          SliverAppBar(
            floating: true,

            ],
          ),
        ],
        body: FadeTransition(
            opacity: widget.animation,
            child: widget.child),
      ),

    );
  }
```